# What explains this bizarre behavior?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

Consider the sequence $x_{n+1} = 2x_{n}-\frac{1}{x_n},n\geq0 $.

1. For $x_{0} = 0,87$ we have

$$
\begin{aligned}
X(1) &\approx 0,590574712643678 \\
X(2) &\approx -0,512116436915835\\
X(3) &\approx 0,928448055572567\\
X(4) &\approx 0,779829931731029\\
X(5) &\approx 0,277328986805082\\
X(6)&\approx -3,05116776974367\\
X(7)&\approx -5,77459217187698\\
X(8)&\approx -11,37601194123\\
X(9)&\approx-22,6641196146756\\
X(10)&\approx -45,2841166242379\\
X(11)&\approx -90,5461504504763\\
X(12)&\approx -181,081256809127\\
X(13)&\approx -362,156991235554\\
X(14)&\approx -724,311221237654\\
X(15)&\approx -1448,62106185332\\
X(16)&\approx -2897,24143339498\\
X(17)&\approx -5794,48252163406\\
X(18)&\approx -11588,9648706901\\
X(19)&\approx -23177,9296550913\\
X(20)&\approx -46355,8592670381\\
X(21)&\approx -92711,718512504\\\
X(22) &\approx -185423,437014222\\
X(23) &\approx -370846,874023051\\
X(24) &\approx -741693,748043405\\
X(25) &\approx -1483387,49608546
\end{aligned}
\begin{aligned}
X(26) &\approx -2966774,99217025\\
X(27) &\approx -5933549,98434016\\
X(28) &\approx -11867099,9686802\\
X(29) &\approx -23734199,9373602\\
X(30) &\approx -47468399,8747204\\
X(31) &\approx -94936799,7494408\\
X(32) &\approx -189873599,498882\\
X(33) &\approx -379747198,997763\\
X(34) &\approx -759494397,995526\\
X(35) &\approx -1518988795,99105\\
X(36) &\approx -3037977591,98211\\
X(37) &\approx -6075955183,96421\\
X(38) &\approx -12151910367,9284\\
X(39) &\approx -24303820735,8568\\
X(40) &\approx -48607641471,7137\\
X(41) &\approx -97215282943,4274\\
X(42) &\approx -194430565886,855\\
X(43) &\approx -388861131773,709\\
X(44) &\approx -777722263547,419\\
X(45) &\approx -1555444527094,84\\
X(46) &\approx -3110889054189,68\\
X(47) &\approx -6221778108379,35\\
X(48) &\approx -12443556216758,7\\
X(49) &\approx -24887112433517,4\\
X(50) &\approx -49774224867034,8
\end{aligned}
$$

and for $x_{0} = 0,88$ we have

$$
\begin{aligned}
X(1) &\approx 0,623636363636364\\
X(2) &\approx -0,356225815001326\\
X(3) &\approx 2,09475648880333\\
X(4) &\approx 3,71213052034011\\
X(5) &\approx 7,15487396107172\\
X(6) &\approx 14,1699830562016\\
X(7) &\approx 28,2693943978123\\
X(8) &\approx 56,503414850717\\
X(9) &\approx 112,989131656057\\
X(10) &\approx 225,969412903359\\
X(11) &\approx 451,934400429021\\
X(12) &\approx 903,866588147526\\
X(13) &\approx 1807,73206993709\\
X(14) &\approx 3615,46358669485\\
X(15) &\approx 7230,9268968\\
X(16) &\approx 14461,8536553051\\
X(17) &\approx 28923,7072414629\\
X(18) &\approx 57847,414448352\\
X(19) &\approx 115694,828879417\\
X(20) &\approx 231389,657750191\\
X(21) &\approx 462779,31549606\\
X(22) &\approx 925558,630989959\\
X(23) &\approx 1851117,26197884\\
X(24) &\approx 3702234,52395714\\
X(25) &\approx 7404469,047914
\end{aligned}
\begin{aligned}
X(26) &\approx 14808938,0958279\\
X(27) &\approx 29617876,1916557\\
X(28) &\approx 59235752,3833113\\
X(29) &\approx 118471504,766623\\
X(30) &\approx 236943009,533245\\
X(31) &\approx 473886019,06649\\
X(32) &\approx 947772038,13298\\
X(33) &\approx 1895544076,26596\\
X(34) &\approx 3791088152,53192\\
X(35) &\approx 7582176305,06384\\
X(36) &\approx 15164352610,1277\\
X(37) &\approx 30328705220,2554\\
X(38) &\approx 60657410440,5108\\
X(39) &\approx 121314820881,022\\
X(40) &\approx 242629641762,043\\
X(41) &\approx 485259283524,086\\
X(42) &\approx 970518567048,172\\
X(43) &\approx 1941037134096,34\\
X(44) &\approx 3882074268192,69\\
X(45) &\approx 7764148536385,38\\
X(46) &\approx 15528297072770,8\\
X(47) &\approx 31056594145541,5\\
X(48) &\approx 62113188291083\\
X(49) &\approx 124226376582166\\
X(50) &\approx 248452753164332
\end{aligned}
$$

What explains this?

Also, is it possible to determine the number $q$ located between $0.87$ and $0.88$ in the radical change of behavior occurs this sequence?

Comment: what is there to explain ?

Comment: This is called chaos, or The Butterfly Effect.

Comment: sensitive dependence on initial conditions.

Comment: It is possible to determine the number "q" located between 0.87 and 0.88 in the radical change of behavior occurs this sequence?

Comment: DO NOT close this question. I think this is a valid question.

Comment: Speaking as someone who voted to close this question, I would vote to reopen it if the OP edited it to be explicit about what s/he considered bizarre, rather than making us all guess.

Comment: [There might be *many* q's.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_fractal)

Comment: It is somewhat reminiscent of the logistic map, which is a typical example of chaos in fairly simple systems.

Comment: @Micah, you are being snobbish! This really is extraordinary behaviour if you haven't seen it before.

Comment: For what it's worth, a turning point is close to $0.8702890362522919$.

Comment: @TonyK: *What* behavior is extraordinary? It's not extraordinary if you don't see it! And it's very easy not to see it when a wall of digits is thrown at you. I confess *I* only noticed because I already know what "sensitive independence on initial conditions" means, from which I guessed what the OP might be looking at, and only then did I notice the signs. Of course, the OP could just as well have observed something else entirely, and we're just substituting our own feelings about what is interesting into the void the OP left.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answers of mercio and Mark Bennet explain how to find the antecedents of $1$, $0$, and $-1$.  This answer may help to visualize the structure of the set.

[image: animated schematic]

The horizontal axis represents $x_0$.  The black horizontal line segments at height $1$ indicate intervals on which the limiting value of $x_n$ is $+\infty,$ while the black horizontal line segments at height $-1$ indicate intervals on which the limiting value of $x_n$ is $-\infty.$  The colored dots at heights $\pm1$ indicate values of $x_0$ for which the fixed points $\pm1$ are reached, while the colored dots on the horizontal axis represent values of $x_0$ for which the fixed point $\infty$ is reached (by first reaching $0$).  Redder colors indicate fixed points that are reached in a small number of iterations; bluer colors indicate fixed points that are reached in a larger number of iterations.  The image is animated.  If the animation has stopped, it may be necessary to reload the page.

**Some data:**

$x_0$ reaching fixed points $(1,\infty,-1)$ after $1$ step:
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 -0.5 & 0. & 0.5 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

$x_0$ reaching fixed points $(1,\infty,-1)$ after $2$ steps:
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 -0.84307 & -0.707107 & -0.59307 \\
 0.59307 & 0.707107 & 0.84307 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

$x_0$ reaching fixed points $(1,\infty,-1)$ after $3$ steps:
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 -0.948618 & -0.905646 & -0.870752 \\
 -0.574217 & -0.552092 & -0.527083 \\
 0.527083 & 0.552092 & 0.574217 \\
 0.870752 & 0.905646 & 0.948618 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

$x_0$ reaching fixed points $(1,\infty,-1)$ after $4$ steps:
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 -0.982971 & -0.968882 & -0.957545 \\
 -0.865086 & -0.858475 & -0.851051 \\
 -0.587509 & -0.582428 & -0.577977 \\
 -0.522169 & -0.516059 & -0.508662 \\
 0.508662 & 0.516059 & 0.522169 \\
 0.577977 & 0.582428 & 0.587509 \\
 0.851051 & 0.858475 & 0.865086 \\
 0.957545 & 0.968882 & 0.982971 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

$x_0$ reaching fixed points $(1,\infty,-1)$ after $5$ steps:
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 -0.994334 & -0.989663 & -0.985915 \\
 -0.955713 & -0.953578 & -0.951185 \\
 -0.869077 & -0.86755 & -0.866214 \\
 -0.849598 & -0.847795 & -0.845616 \\
 -0.591285 & -0.589765 & -0.588514 \\
 -0.577225 & -0.576336 & -0.575323 \\
 -0.52566 & -0.524341 & -0.52317 \\
 -0.507143 & -0.505222 & -0.502849 \\
 0.502849 & 0.505222 & 0.507143 \\
 0.52317 & 0.524341 & 0.52566 \\
 0.575323 & 0.576336 & 0.577225 \\
 0.588514 & 0.589765 & 0.591285 \\
 0.845616 & 0.847795 & 0.849598 \\
 0.866214 & 0.86755 & 0.869077 \\
 0.951185 & 0.953578 & 0.955713 \\
 0.985915 & 0.989663 & 0.994334 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Explanation:** Taking the first row of the last table,
$$\begin{pmatrix} -0.994334 & -0.989663 & -0.985915\end{pmatrix},$$
as an example,

- $x_0=-0.994334$ implies $x_n=1$ for $n\ge5;$
- $x_0=-0.989663$ implies $x_n=\infty$ for $n\ge5$ since $x_4=0;$
- $x_0=-0.985915$ implies $x_n=-1$ for $n\ge5;$
- for $x_0\in(-0.994334,-0.989663),$ we have $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=+\infty;$
- for $x_0\in(-0.989663,-0.985915),$ we have $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=-\infty.$

The decimal numbers in this discussion should, of course, be replaced by the algebraic numbers they approximate.

**Added:** Here's a better answer than the one I gave in the comments (now deleted) to your question about how one knows that the sequence converges to $+\infty$ for  $x_0\in(-0.994334,-0.989663).$  In addition, I will try to clarify what $+\infty$ and $-\infty$ are.  I should also say that nearly everything there is to know about this problem is well-covered in mercio's answer.  Since it took me a while to understand where all of his statements come from, I provide some of the details I was able to fill in, in case they're helpful to you or others.

It is a little bit neater to work with the real line extended by the point at infinity.  One can do this formally by working on the projective line whose points are $(a,b),$ with $a,$ $b$ not both zero, and with the equivalence relation $(a,b)\sim(\lambda a,\lambda b)$ for any non-zero $\lambda.$  Then the real number $x$ is identified with $(x,1)$ and $\infty$ is identified with $(0,1).$  Arithmetic works as follows:
$$
\begin{aligned}
(a,b)\cdot(c,d)&=(ac,bd)\\
\frac{1}{(a,b)}&=(b,a)\\
(a,b)+(c,d)&=(ad+bc,bd)\\
-(a,b)&=(-a,b).
\end{aligned}
$$
The map $x\mapsto2x-\frac{1}{x}$ becomes $(a,b)\mapsto(2a^2-b^2,ab).$  This formulation allows us to say things like
$$0\leftrightarrow(0,1)\mapsto(-1,0)\sim(1,0)\leftrightarrow\infty,$$
and
$$\infty\leftrightarrow(1,0)\mapsto(2,0)\sim(1,0)\leftrightarrow\infty.$$

In this system there is no distinction between the point $\infty$ and the point $-\infty.$  Nevertheless, it turns out that if the sequence $x_0,$ $x_1,$ $x_2,\ldots$ converges to $\infty,$ then it does so either through positive values only or through negative values only.  In no case does a sequence that converges to $\infty$ alternate infinitely many times between positive and negative.  For this reason, it makes sense to make statements like "the sequence converges to $+\infty$" or "the sequence converges to $-\infty$" as shorthand.  The only other way that  sequence can converge to $\infty$ is for it to map there directly.  This happens either if $x_0=\infty$ or if one of $x_0,$ $x_1,$ $x_2,\ldots$ equals $0.$  From now on, I will drop the formal language of ordered pairs.  I hope it will be clear what I mean when I refer to $\infty,$ $+\infty,$ and $-\infty.$

To verify the statement above that a sequence converging to $\infty$ does so either through positive values only or through negative values only, compute the first and second differences:
$$\begin{aligned}&x_{n+1}-x_n=x_n-\frac{1}{x_n}\\
&(x_{n+2}-x_{n+1})-(x_{n+1}-x_n)=x_{n+1}-\frac{1}{x_{n+1}}-x_n+\frac{1}{x_n}=x_n-\frac{1}{x_{n+1}}.
\end{aligned}$$
If $x_n>1,$ the first and second differences are both positive, so the sequence $x_n,$ $x_{n+1},$ $x_{n+2},\ldots$ is monotonically increasing towards $+\infty.$  Since the map $x\mapsto2x-\frac{1}{x}$ is an odd function, we also conclude that if $x_n<1$ then $x_n,$ $x_{n+1},$ $x_{n+2},\ldots$ is monotonically decreasing towards $-\infty.$

Regarding the projective line as a circle, the map $f:x\mapsto2x-\frac{1}{x}$ is continuous and covers the circle exactly twice.  Specifically, $f$ is increasing on each of the intervals $(-\infty,0)$ and $(0,+\infty)$ and maps both of them onto the interval $(-\infty,+\infty)$.

To understand the full set of points $x_0$ that generate sequences converging to $\infty,$ we determine the set of points $S_n$ that have **not** reached $(1,+\infty)\cup\{\infty\}\cup(-\infty,-1)$ after $n$ iterations of $f,$ with $n=0,1,2,\ldots.$  Equivalently, we determine the set of points $x_0$ such that $x_n\in[-1,1].$  Clearly
$$S_0=[-1,1].$$
Given any point $x,$ the preimages of $x$ are
$$
\begin{aligned}
p_-(x)&=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{4}\left(x-\sqrt{x^2+8}\right) & \text{$x$ real,}\\ 0 & x=\infty,\end{cases}\\
p_+(x)&=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{4}\left(x+\sqrt{x^2+8}\right) & \text{$x$ real,}\\ \infty & x=\infty.\end{cases}
\end{aligned}
$$
Observe that $p_-$ is increasing and maps $(-\infty,\infty)$ onto $(-\infty,0),$ and that $p_+$ is increasing and maps $(-\infty,\infty)$ onto $(0,\infty).$  The image of the interval $[-1,1]$ under $p_-$ is $\left[-1,-\frac{1}{2}\right].$  (This image lies within $[-1,1],$ as it must, since, under the map $f,$ a point outside of $[-1,1]$ maps to a point outside of $[-1,1].$)  Similarly, the image of the interval $[-1,1]$ under $p_+$ is $\left[\frac{1}{2},1\right].$  Therefore
$$
S_1=p_-(S_0)\cup p_+(S_0)=\left[-1,-\frac{1}{2}\right]\cup\left[\frac{1}{2},1\right].
$$
In a similar manner,
$$
\begin{aligned}
S_2=&p_-(S_1)\cup p_+(S_1)\\
=&p_-\left(\left[-1,-\frac{1}{2}\right]\right)\cup p_-\left(\left[\frac{1}{2},1\right]\right)\cup p_+\left(\left[-1,-\frac{1}{2}\right]\right)\cup p_+\left(\left[\frac{1}{2},1\right]\right)\\
=&[-1,-0.84307]\cup[-0.59307,-0.5]\cup[0.5,0.59307]\cup[0.84307,1].
\end{aligned}
$$
The approximations $0.59307$ and $0.84307$ actually stand for the algebraic numbers
$$\frac{1}{8}\left(-1+\sqrt{33}\right)\approx0.59307,\qquad\frac{1}{8}\left(1+\sqrt{33}\right)\approx0.84307.$$  Continuing in the same way, applying $p_-$ and $p_+$ to each of the four intervals making up $S_2,$ we get
$$
\begin{aligned}
S_3=&[-1,-0.94862]\cup[-0.87075,-0.84307]\cup[-0.59307,-0.57422]\cup[-0.52708,-0.5]\\
&\cup[0.5,0.52708]\cup[0.57422,0.59307]\cup[0.84307,0.87075]\cup[0.94862,1].
\end{aligned}
$$
The intervals with negative endpoints come from the application of $p_-,$ while those with positive endpoints come from the application of $p_+.$  Likewise,
$$
\begin{aligned}
S_4=&[-1, -0.98297]\cup[-0.95754, -0.94862]\\
&\cup[-0.87075, -0.86509]\cup[-0.85105, -0.84307]\\
&\cup[-0.59307, -0.58751]\cup[-0.57798, -0.57422]\\
&\cup[-0.52708, -0.52217]\cup[-0.50866, -0.5]\\
&\cup[0.5, 0.50866]\cup[0.52217,0.52708]\\
&\cup[0.57422, 0.57798]\cup[0.58751, 0.59307]\\
&\cup[0.84307, 0.85105]\cup[0.86509, 0.87075]\\
&\cup[0.94862, 0.95754]\cup[0.98297, 1]
\end{aligned}
$$
and
$$
\begin{aligned}
S_5=&[-1, -0.99433]\cup[-0.98592, -0.98297]\\
&\cup[-0.95754, -0.95571]\cup[-0.95119, -0.94862]\\
&\cup[-0.87075, -0.86908]\cup[-0.86621, -0.86509]\\ 
&\cup[-0.85105, -0.84960]\cup[-0.84562, -0.84307]\\
&\cup[-0.59307, -0.59128]\cup[-0.58851, -0.58751]\\
&\cup[-0.57798, -0.57722]\cup[-0.57532, -0.57422]\\ 
&\cup[-0.52708, -0.52566]\cup[-0.52317, -0.52217]\\
&\cup[-0.50866, -0.50714]\cup[-0.50285, -0.5]\\
&\cup[0.5, 0.50285]\cup[0.50714, 0.50866]\\
&\cup[0.52217, 0.52317]\cup[0.52566, 0.52708]\\
&\cup[0.57422, 0.57532]\cup[0.57722, 0.57798]\\ 
&\cup[0.58751, 0.58851]\cup[0.59128, 0.59307]\\
&\cup[0.84307, 0.84562]\cup[0.84960, 0.85105]\\
&\cup[0.86509, 0.86621]\cup[0.86908, 0.87075]\\
&\cup[0.94862, 0.95119]\cup[0.95571, 0.95754]\\
&\cup[0.98297, 0.98592]\cup[0.99433, 1].
\end{aligned}
$$

To make the foregoing more explicit, we parameterize intervals and their endpoints by sign sequences.  Let $\sigma_0\sigma_1\sigma_2,\ldots$ be a sequence of signs: $\sigma_j\in\{-,+\},$ $j\in\{0,1,2,\ldots\}.$  Define
$$
\begin{aligned}
L()&=-1\\
R()&=1\\
I()&=[L(),R()]=[-1,1],
\end{aligned}
$$
where the empty argument denotes the zero length sequence; for $\ell>0,$ define
$$
\begin{aligned}
L\left(\sigma_0\sigma_1\ldots\sigma_{\ell-1}\right)&=p_{\sigma_0}\left(L\left(\sigma_1\sigma_2\ldots\sigma_{\ell-1}\right)\right)\\
R\left(\sigma_0\sigma_1\ldots\sigma_{\ell-1}\right)&=p_{\sigma_0}\left(R\left(\sigma_1\sigma_2\ldots\sigma_{\ell-1}\right)\right)\\
I\left(\sigma_0\sigma_1\ldots\sigma_{\ell-1}\right)&=\left[L\left(\sigma_0\sigma_1\ldots\sigma_{\ell-1}\right),R\left(\sigma_0\sigma_1\ldots\sigma_{\ell-1}\right)\right].
\end{aligned}
$$
Let $Q_\ell=\{\sigma=\sigma_0\sigma_1\ldots\sigma_{\ell-1}\vert \sigma_j\in\{-,+\},\ j\in\{0,1,\ldots,\ell-1\}\}$ be the set of all sign sequences of length $\ell.$
Then
$$
S_\ell=\bigcup_{\sigma\in Q_\ell} I\left(\sigma_0\sigma_1\ldots\sigma_{\ell-1}\right).
$$
Observe that if sign sequences, $\sigma=\sigma_0\sigma_1\ldots\sigma_{\ell-1}$ and $\tau=\tau_0\tau_1\ldots\tau_{\ell-1}$ are compared lexicographically, then for $\sigma<\tau,$ we have $L(\sigma)<L(\tau)$ and $R(\sigma)<R(\tau).$  Furthermore, we have $L(\sigma)<R(\sigma).$  These statements are proved inductively using the property that $p_-$ and $p_+$ are increasing and $L()<R().$

Note that the interval $S_0=I$ is of length $2,$ and that the sum of the lengths of the two intervals $I_-$ and $I_+$ making up $S_1$ is $1.$  Moreover, the sum of the lengths of the intervals making up $S_n$ is $2^{1-n}.$  That is, the total length of $S_\ell$ is halved with every iteration.  Turning things around, the total length of the intervals containing points in $[-1,1]$ that wind up in $(1,\infty)\cup\{\infty\}\cup(-\infty,-1)$ after $n$ applications of $f$ is $2\left(1-2^{-n}\right),$ which means that almost all points in $[-1,1]$ converge to $\infty.$

To see why this is true, observe that each set $S_n,$ $n>0,$ is the union of pairs of intervals of the form $[-b,-a]\cup[a,b]$ where $b>a>0.$  Specifically, such a pair is formed by a pair of complementary sign sequences:
$$
a=L(\sigma),\quad b=R(\sigma),\quad -b=L(\overline\sigma),\quad -a=R(\overline\sigma),
$$
with $\sigma_0=+$ and where $\overline\sigma$ denotes the sequence obtained by negating every element of $\sigma.$
Under $p_-,$ this pair maps to
$$
\left[\frac{1}{4}\left(-b-\sqrt{b^2+8}\right),\frac{1}{4}\left(-a-\sqrt{a^2+8}\right)\right]\cup\left[\frac{1}{4}\left(a-\sqrt{a^2+8}\right),\frac{1}{4}\left(b-\sqrt{b^2+8}\right)\right],
$$
which has total length $\frac{1}{2}(b-a).$  Similarly, the image of the pair under $p_+$ has length $\frac{1}{2}(b-a).$  Since $S_{n+1}$ is the union of the images of $S_n$ under $p_-$ and $p_+,$ the pair $[-b,-a]\cup[a,b],$ of total length $2(b-a),$ maps to intervals of total length $b-a$ in $S_{n+1}.$

We have understood the process of producing $S_{n+1}$ from $S_n$ as one of applying the maps $p_-$ and $p_+$ to $S_n,$ and then taking the union of the results.  It can also be understood as a process of deleting an open interval from the middle region of each of the closed intervals making up $S_n.$  Observe that, for $\sigma=\sigma_0\sigma_1\ldots\sigma_{n-1},$ we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
L(\sigma--\ldots-)&=L(\sigma),\\
R(\sigma++\ldots+)&=R(\sigma).
\end{aligned}
$$
The first of these follows by noting that
$$L(\sigma)=p_{\sigma_0}(p_{\sigma_1}(\ldots p_{\sigma_{n-1}}(-1)\ldots)),$$
and then observing that $p_-(-1)=-1.$  The second follows similarly from
$$R(\sigma)=p_{\sigma_0}(p_{\sigma_1}(\ldots p_{\sigma_{n-1}}(1)\ldots))$$
and $p_+(1)=1.$  Therefore, the interval $I(\sigma)=[L(\sigma),R(\sigma)]$ in $S_n$ becomes two intervals
$$
I(\sigma-)\cup I(\sigma+)=[L(\sigma-),R(\sigma-)]\cup[L(\sigma+),R(\sigma+)]
$$
in $S_{n+1}.$  The outermost endpoints stay the same: $L(\sigma-)=L(\sigma),$ $R(\sigma+)=R(\sigma).$  Two new interior endpoints are created by removing the open interval $(R(\sigma-),L(\sigma+)).$  This viewpoint of the process of creating $S_{n+1}$ from $S_n$ makes it clear that $S_{n+1}\subset S_n.$

The points in the removed open interval, $(R(\sigma-),L(\sigma+)),$ are points that map outside of $[-1,1]$ under $f^{\circ(n+1)}.$  There is some point $B(\sigma-)\in(R(\sigma-),L(\sigma+))$ such that $f^{\circ(n+1)}$ maps $(R(\sigma-),B(\sigma-))$ to $(1,\infty)$ and $(B(\sigma-),L(\sigma+))$ to $(-\infty,-1).$  The point $B(\sigma)$ is the preimage of $\infty,$ defined by
$$
\begin{aligned}
B()&=\infty,\\
B\left(\sigma_0\sigma_1\ldots\sigma_{\ell-1}\right)&=p_{\sigma_0}\left(B\left(\sigma_1\sigma_2\ldots\sigma_{\ell-1}\right)\right).
\end{aligned}
$$
We can therefore say that points in $(-0.994334,-0.989663)$ converge to $+\infty$ because
$$
-0.994334\approx R(-----),\quad -0.989663\approx B(-----),
$$
and hence $f^{\circ5}$ maps points in the interval to $(1,\infty).$  Likewise, points in $(-0.989663,-0.985915)$ converge to $-\infty$ because $-0.985915\approx L(----+)$ and hence $f^{\circ5}$ maps point in this interval to $(-\infty,-1).$

The set of real numbers that do not converge to $\infty$ is
$$
S=S_0\cap S_1\cap S_2\cap\ldots.
$$
In comments to his answer, mercio states that there is a one-to-one correspondence between points of $S$ and semi-infinite sign sequences $\sigma=\sigma_0\sigma_1\sigma_2\ldots.$  To see why this is so, observe that
$$
I(\sigma_0)\supset I(\sigma_0\sigma_1)\supset I(\sigma_0\sigma_1\sigma_2)\supset\ldots.
$$
Hence the sequence of intervals associated with finite initial subsequences of $\sigma$ is a set of nested intervals.  By [Cantor's Intersection Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_intersection_theorem), the intersection of a set of nested closed intervals whose diameter tends to $0$ contains a single point.  Call this point $x(\sigma).$

The image of the interval $I(\sigma_0\sigma_1\ldots\sigma_{\ell-1})$ under $f$ is $I(\sigma_1\sigma_2\ldots\sigma_{\ell-1})$ since $f(p_{\sigma_0}(x))=x.$  It follows that
$$f(x(\sigma_0\sigma_1\sigma_2\ldots))=x(\sigma_1\sigma_2\sigma_3\ldots).$$
This implies that sign sequences with period $\ell$ are associated with points that have orbits of period $\ell$ under $f.$  (Proof: Let $\sigma$ have period $\ell:$ $\sigma=\sigma_0\sigma_1\ldots\sigma_{\ell-1}\sigma.$  Then
$$f^{\circ\ell}(x(\sigma))=f^{\circ\ell}(x(\sigma_0\sigma_1\ldots\sigma_{\ell-1}\sigma)=x(\sigma).$$
Furthermore, $f^{\circ j}(x(\sigma))\ne x(\sigma)$ for $j<\ell$ since the map $\sigma\mapsto x(\sigma)$ is one-to-one.)

You ask whether there are non-periodic orbits that do not converge to $\infty.$  The comments of mercio imply yes.  In fact, any non-periodic sign sequence $\sigma$ produces an $x(\sigma)$ that has such a non-periodic orbit.

Comment: How can you justify that to the limit of the sequence $x_0\in (-0,994334,-0,989663)$ is infinite. What is $+\infty$ and it is $-\infty$?

Comment: My previous comments in response to your question were misleading, so I've deleted them, and expanded my answer instead.  In particular, there was nothing non-rigourous about the statement that points in $(-0.994334,-0.989663)$ converge to $+\infty$ as I had stated in my comment.  (I'd forgotten how I carried out the original calculations back in May 2013.

Answer (score 9):

Extending the function $f : x \mapsto 2x- \frac 1x$ to the circle $\Bbb R \cup \{\infty\}$ by defining $f(0) = f(\infty) = \infty$,
$f$ is a $2$-to-$1$ function with $3$ fixpoints, one attractive ($\infty$), and two repulsive ($1,-1$).

So, for most starting reals, the generated sequence will "converge" to $\infty$. Since $f$ is continuous, the set of reals that generate a sequence diverging to $+ \infty$ is an open subset, as well as the set of reals that generate a sequence diverging to $- \infty$.

those two open sets "come in contact" at the real numbers that generate a sequence eventually going to $0$ and then that stays on $\infty$. Here, you can plainly see that there is an $x \in (0.87 ; 0.88)$ such that $f^{6}(x) = 0$.

To find the precise value of that $x$, you need to compute the successive antecedents of $0$ by $f$ that lay in-between the two sequences.

$f^{-1}(y) = \frac{y \pm \sqrt {y^2+8}}4$, so the first one is $\frac {\sqrt 2}2$ (betwwen the two $X(5)$ values), then $\frac {\sqrt 2 + \sqrt {34}}8$ (between the two $X(4)$ values), and you can go on until you reach the incriminating $x \in (0.87;0.88)$.

Also, the set of all the antecedents of $0$ has accumulation points (starting with $1$ and $-1$, but they could be more), so it's very possible to find many incriminating values between the two initial values, by going back long enough in the antecedents tree.

Comment: Indeed, there are many incriminating values between $0.87$ and $0.88$. They all seem to be located between $0.8702$ and $0.8708$. (The point with $f^6(x) = 0$ is $x \approx 0.870427$.)

Comment: @TMM : I think the closure of the antecedents of $0$ (or any $x \in [-1;1]$) is a Cantor set (independent of $x$).

Comment: @TMM : $x_2=-1$ for $x_0=(1+\sqrt{33})/8\approx0.84307,$ while $x_3=1$ for $x_0=\left(\sqrt{2(273-\sqrt{33})}+\sqrt{33}-1\right)/32\approx0.870752.$  The limiting value of $x_n$ changes from $+\infty$ to $-\infty$ infinitely often between these two values.  The least critical value greater than $0.87$ is $x_0\approx0.870214,$ at which point $x_6=-1,$ so one can also say that the limiting value of $x_n$ changes from $+\infty$ to $-\infty$ infinitely often between $\approx0.870214$ and $\approx0.870752.$

Comment: How can you justify that point $\infty$ is attractive?

Comment: @medicu : if $|x| \ge 2$ then $|2x-1/x| \ge 2|x|-1/2 \ge |x|+3/2$ so this means we do have a basin of attraction around $\infty$. More precisely, the circle is a $C^1$ variety, and if you compute the differential of $f$ at $\infty$ (for example by using the chart $x = 1/t$ which sends $t=0$ to $\infty$) then you find $df(\infty) = 1/2$, which means $\infty$ is attractive.

Comment: I noticed that for $x_0=+-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$sequence is periodic with period 2. Perhaps there are other periodicity. In these cases $+-\infty$ are points of attraction. Why?

Comment: The set of starting points that don't generate a sequence that converge to $\infty$ is a Cantor subset $S$ of $[-1;1]$. $S$ has uncountably many points and is fixed by $f$. For $x \in S$ you can attach a sequence of signs $\phi(x) = (sign(f^{\circ n}(x)))_{n \in \Bbb N}$, and $\phi$ is actually a bijection from $S$ to $\{+,-\}^\Bbb N$ (which can be made continuous with the adequate topology on those sequences). We clearly have $\phi \circ f \circ \phi^{-1} ((s_n)_{n \in \Bbb N}) = (s_{n+1})_{n \in \Bbb N}$.

Comment: Now via this $\phi$ the points in the Cantor set that generate a periodic sequence correspond exactly to the periodic sign sequences. There are a lot of them, and none of them is attractive.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I have seen such a sequence can be periodic or infinite limit. I wonder if he can have another behavior that is to be divergent infinite set of terms (but do not have infinite limit).

Comment: @medicu: the comments above by mercio imply that the answer to your last question is yes.  I've provided some additional details in my own answer, in case the reasons are not immediately clear.

Answer (score 6):

The recurrence has fixed points at 1 and -1.

If $x_n \lt -1$ then the sequence becomes increasingly negative.

If $x_n \gt 1$ then the sequence becomes increasingly positive.

The sequence crashes if $x_n=0$

The behaviour outside the interval $(-1,1)$ is clear, so we don't need long strings of values to explain it.

The way to understand what is going on is to see that the interval $(-1,1)$ can be separated into subintervals in which the values exhibit the same behaviour. The behaviour changes when we pass through a critical point - and these are just the points at which the sequence eventually terminates at $0$ or $\pm1$.

So, for example, if $x_n \in (-0.5,0)$ we find that $x_{n+1} \gt 1$
and $x_n \in (0,0.5)$ gives $x_{n+1} \lt -1$. The behaviour changes as we pass through $0$.

We note that if $x_n=\pm0.5$ then $x_{n+1}=\mp1$, so these are critical points. Also if $x_n=\pm \frac {\sqrt 2} 2$ then $x_{n+1}=0$.

If $x=a$ is a critical point, we get the next one(s) - the point(s) which map onto $a$ - by solving $2x-\cfrac 1 x=a$, this is equivalent to $$2x^2-ax-1=0$$ with solutions $$\frac {a\pm\sqrt{a^2+8}}4$$

Comment: Thank you! I noticed the same thing myself. I have tried to describe the set of "bad" but I could not.

Answer (score 0):

If you make the transformation $y_n=\sqrt{2}x_n$, then the equation is transformed to $$y_{n+1}=2\left(y_n-\frac{1}{y_n}\right),\ n\geq 0$$

So, basically we're talking about the following kind of map $$f(x)=\lambda\left(x+\frac{a}{x}\right),\ a,x\in \mathbb{R},\  \lambda
>0$$ For $a<0$, this function has fixed points at $x={}_{-}^+\sqrt{\frac{\lambda a}{1-\lambda}},\infty$. ${}_{-}^+\sqrt{-a}$ are both attracting for $0<\lambda<1$ and repelling for $\lambda>1$. $\infty$ is attracting for $\lambda<1$. This mapping exhibits rich dynamics as good as the famous logistic map.